# What must I do to edit a text file in the config page of a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that uses a list of strings, currently read as an array from a text file using the `file()` function. I would now like to be able to offer the blog owner the ability to edit this list of strings in the config page for my plugin. How can I best go about this?

I guess my main questions here are how to write my changed list back to the text file, and then, whether there is a better way of storing this list than a text file. Other options that come to mind are to store it as a custom post type, and enjoy the out-of-box versioning of the WP post editor, or keep things simple and store this list of strings as an array in the wp_option table. All suggestions will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [`register_setting`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) would be the best way to go for just a list of strings. then call [`get_option`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to retrieve values. Creating a separated table is kind of overkilled.

Comment: `get_option` / `set_option` uses the database (so it's a bit misleading that you call using the database overkill), and it's a standard way to do so in wordpress. So +1.

Comment: @hakre, thanks for your comment. I see the misleading here. what I was going to say is creating a separated table is kind of overkilled. I will update the comment now.

Comment: @hakre, yes, `get_/set_option` use the database, but I don't use the database directly, so e.g. whatever table WP deems right to store options in will be used, and I will never be trying to use the wrong table.

Comment: @bingjie2680, how does `register_setting` compare to `add_option`?

Comment: @ProfK: bingjie added links to the question which give you the documentation of both. In short, both are related to settings, but `get/add_option` is just an interface to the db storage layer, while `register_setting` provides an interface to set the value(s).

Comment: @Profk, hakre has explained well. additionally, register_setting can register a group of settings while add_option only adds single name-value paired to a table.

Answer (score 0):

You should store it in the database instead of a file. You can make the plugin create a new table in the database when it is installed.

Comment: I feel for this application it is complicating things too much to require a new database table.